# Script, input with addClass and link.attr

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I'm trying to wrap my head around this script.
I'm not the best with JavaScript and jQuery yet, but I'm trying to learn.

```
<script>
  var link = $("#to-toggle");
  $("#toggle").on("change", function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      .addClass("active");
      link.attr("href", link.data("href"));
    } else {
      .removeClass("active");
      link.removeAttr("href");
    }
  });
</script>
```

Before I added the `.addClass` and `.removeClass` it worked fine, but I can't seem to be able to get a class to toggle as well, when my check box is checked/unchecked.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `.addClass("active");` operating on the air, you need to use element on which this function to call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot where to add and remove the class to/from ---> `link`:

```
if(this.checked) {
    link.addClass("active");
    link.attr("href", link.data("href"));
} else {
    link.removeClass("active");
    link.removeAttr("href");
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the quick help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming  #toggle to be your checbox Id and you are trying to add and remove class to this checbox, replace your line 
   .addClass("active");

By 
   $(this).addClass("active");

Similarly replace 
      .removeClass("active");

By 
$(this).removeClass("active");

I am on mobile, excuse me for format issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(this.checked) {
    $(this).addClass("active");
    link.attr("href", link.data("href"));
} else {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
    link.removeAttr("href");
}
});
```